# How do I create an AWS API Gateway usageplan with a Marketplace productCode

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-marketplace

I'm selling a SaaS service through AWS Marketplace. When setting up an API Gateway, it's useful to associate the Marketplace productCode to the usagePlan.

While, the productCode can be set through the AWS web console and is returned when calling `get-usage-plan`, there seems to be no way to set the productCode, either while creating or afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `update-usage-plan` API Gateway method and `add` the `/productCode` path.

E.g. Using the AWS CLI:

```
aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id abc123 --patch-operations op="add",path="/productCode",value="s5a8d5kqgg8ymke2yjxx"
```